# how to redirect to my specified page in codeigniter

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter

I have created a login page using **codeigniter** framework
inside the `models` folder I created
`login_model.php`

```
class Login_model extends CI_Model 
{ //CI version 3.0
function validate_login()
{
    $this->db->where('username', $this->input->post('username'));//this is form username
    $this->db->where('password', md5($this->input->post('password')));//this is form password
    $query = $this->db->get('membership'); //database autoloaded

    if($query->num_rows == 1)
    {
        return true;
    }
  }
  }
```

I think here everything fine after this
inside the `controllers` folder I created
`login_control.php`

```
class Login_control extends CI_Controller 
{
function index() 
{
    $data['main_content'] = 'login_view'; 
    $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);
}

function validate_credential() {
    $this->load->model('login_model');
    $query = $this->login_model->validate_login();
    //redirect('logged_site/members_area');

    if($query)//if user credential validate!. run following events
    {
        $newdata = array(
                'username'  => $this->input->post('username'),
                'logged_in' => TRUE
        );

        $this->session->set_userdata($newdata);

        redirect('logged_site/members_area');
    } 
    else 
    {
        $this->index();
    }
  }
 }
```

here If I give directly redirect to `members_area` page it is working as follows

```
redirect('logged_site/members_area');
```

after comment above line I used `if/else` condition to validate query but after this condition coding not redirecting to specified page and without any error just staying in `$this->index();` page which is available in `else` part.
Please help me where I made mistake?

Comment: What you mean by $this->index();?

Comment: if condition false go to `login_view` page

Comment: What is the return value of validate_login()?

Comment: @HaitherAli answer is added. Check

Comment: I checked already in this way too but not redirecting

Comment: @SanjayKumarNS validate_login()? returning **num_rows** from database which is `1` true `0` false

Comment: @HaitherAli check now

Comment: Have you tried echoing the value  $query?

Comment: Note: md5 are not good any more for login passwords un-secure and it's old here is current way of hashing password http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error on your model `validate_login()`

Change:

```
 if($query->num_rows == 1)
```

To:

```
if($query->num_rows() == 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

do like this

**In Controller**

```
if($query == true) # check true
{
    $newdata = array(
            'username'  => $this->input->post('username'),
            'logged_in' => TRUE
    );

    $this->session->set_userdata($newdata);

    redirect('logged_site/members_area');
} 
else 
{
    $this->index();
}
```

**In Model**

```
class Login_model extends CI_Model 
{
    function validate_login()
    {
        $this->db->where('username', $this->input->post('username'));//this is form username
        $this->db->where('password', md5($this->input->post('password')));//this is form password
        $query = $this->db->get('membership'); //database autoloaded
        $result = $query->result_array();

        $count = count($result) # add
        if($count == 1) #changed
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```